# Unterschied sensitiv vs. sensibel?

Tags: meaning, difference

Können nur Personen *sensibel* sein?

Etwa, Daten sind deswegen im Gegensatz *sensitiv*.

Comment: Eher andersrum. Auch [ein Thema kann sensibel sein](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sensibel#Bedeutung3). Die Daten, dagegen, können nicht sensitiv sein, weil sie nicht fühlen/empfinden können.

Comment: Wie kommst du darauf, dass nur Personen sensibel sein können? Etwas mehr Kontext wäre schon hilfreich.

Comment: @Eller Also ich kenne die [Sensitivitätsanalyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivit%C3%A4t_(Test)) aus der statistischen Untersuchung von Daten. Aber ansonsten hast du recht.

Answer (score 7):

Kommt auf den Verwendungszusammenhang an. Meistens:

Sensitiv: eher auf der sensorischen, physiologischen Ebene.

Sensibel: eher auf der affektiven, psychologischen Ebene.

Der Unterschied zwischen den  beiden Wörtern "sensitiv" und  "sensibel" sind tatsächlich fundamental. Und undurchsichtig. Wenn man ein Wörterbuch bemüht:

> [**sensitiv** Bedeutungen:](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensibel)
>
> 1. leicht zu beschädigen
> 2. empfindlich auf emotionaler und geistiger Ebene
> 3. überempfindliche Reaktion gegenüber einem Stoff zeigend, beispielsweise in Form einer Allergie gegen … (Inhaltsstoffe in Hautcreme, Medikamente, Penizillin, Pollen, …)
> 4. persönlich vertraulich oder eine gewisse Brisanz bergend
>
> [**sensibel** Bedeutungen:](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensitiv)
>
> 1. empfindlich bis überempfindlich

Allerdings ist der alltagssprachliche Gebrauch der beiden Wörter wesentlich komplizierter in der dokumentierten Bedeutung oder der intendierten Bedeutung. Häufig ist eine synonyme Verwendung.

> [Diese sich daraus ergebenden Schwierigkeiten] Situation ist vorstellbar, wenn man als Sprachinteressierter heraus- finden möchte, was der Unterschied zwischen sensitiv und sensibel ist und für diesen Zweck gängige Bedeutungswörterbücher des Deutschen konsultiert.
>
> Duden sensibel:
>
> - von besonderer Feinfühligkeit; empfindsam
> - (Medizin) empfindlich gegenüber Schmerzen und Reizen von außen; schmerzempfindlich
> - besonders viel Sorgfalt, Umsicht, Fingerspitzengefühl o. Ä. erfordernd, heikel
>
> DWDS sensibel:
>
> - Medizin für Reize empfindlich die sensiblen Nerven nehmen die Reize aus der Umwelt auf und leiten sie dem Zentralnervensystem zu, die sensiblen Nerven- fasern, Nervenstränge
> - empfindsam, feinfühlig
>     ein sensibles Kind
>     ein feinnerviger sensibler Mann
>     eine außerordentlich sensible Frau
>     sie ist von Natur aus zart und sensibel, reagiert auf solche Dinge sehr sensibel
>
> Duden sensitiv:
>
> - von übersteigerter Feinfühligkeit; überempfindlich
>
> DWDS sensitiv:
>
> - sehr empfindlich, leicht reizbar, feinnervig
>
> Petra Storjohann: "Was ist der Unterschied zwischen sensitiv und sensibel?", Zeitschrift für angewandte Linguistik 2015; 62(1): 99–122. (
>   DOI 10.1515/zfal-2015-0004)

Durch den unter anderem per Werbesprache vorangetriebenen Sprachwandel ist das schon länger allgemein bekannte "sensibel" zunehmend dem noch eher fachsprachlichen oder einem Anglizismus verhafteten "sensitiv" als synonyme Verwendungsmöglichkeit angeglichen.

Man beachte auch die deutlichen Bedeutungsunterschiede zwischen englisch [sensitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sensitive) and [sensible](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sensible). Ein Umstand der mehr als eine Übersetzung aus dem englischen Sprachraum völlig verpeilt hat.

> Kaufen sie "Marke sensitiv(e), für sensible Haut, aber pronto!

---

> Können nur Personen sensibel sein?
>   Etwa, Daten sind deswegen im Gegensatz sensitiv.

Nein. Personen können umgangssprachlich "[Sensibelchen](https://www.psychomeda.de/lexikon/hochsensibilitaet.html)" sein, aber auch [sensitiv](http://www.psychosoziale-gesundheit.net/bb/07sensitiv.html):

> Die Psychiater langen da bei der Fach-Bezeichnung sensitiv aber noch ganz anders hin, zumindest die frühere Generation und ihre Definitionen und Klassifikationen. So reiht beispielsweise das führende psychiatrische Wörterbuch in deutscher Sprache die Sensitiven unter die selbstunsicheren Psychopaten ein (siehe Kasten).

Ebenso Daten:

> [Sensitive Daten (auch nach EU-DSGVO)](https://wuw-online.owlit.de/document/zeitschriften/datenschutz-berater/2016/heft-05/beitrage/sensitive-daten-auch-nach-eu-dsgvo/MLX_28fb?authentication=none)

oder

> [Sensible Daten – was Unternehmen wissen müssen](https://www.mein-datenschutzbeauftragter.de/faq/sensible-daten/)

These: vor 30 Jahren waren die meisten Verwendungen von "sensitiv" einfach nur "falsch". Inzwischen ist kaum noch ein Unterschied erkennbar.

---

Notwendiger Kommentar:

Neben den deskriptiven Aspekten, die oben genant wurden, gibt es natürlich noch eine sprachkritische Perspektive. "Sensible Daten" oder "sensitve Daten" sind natürlich nichts als ein Ausdruck der allgemeinen Blähsprechverlotterung. Man sieht es förmlich direkt vor Augen, das kleine, neugeborene Datum, frierend, zitternd und ängstlich den Missbrauch durch kapitalistische Großunternehmen,  den überbordenden Staat oder gewöhnliche Kriminelle erwartend. Warum sollte ein Datum, "sensibel" sein? Daten sind nicht sensitiv, sie haben keine Sensoren (neuerliche Ausnahme durch Punkt 4 der Wiktionarydefinition).

Ist es nun so, dass das kleine, süße Datum zu der Gruppe der Daten gehört, die ‘[empfindsam](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sensitiv), feinfühlig, seelisch leicht beeinflußbar, reizempfindlich’ sind? Oder ist das Datum nun  ‘[empfindsam](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sensibel), feinfühlig, seelisch leicht beeinflußbar, reizempfindlich’?

Daten sind vielleicht schützenswert, nützlich, begehrt. Insofern: Daten können eigentlich weder sensitiv noch schon gar nicht sensibel sein.

> Warum findet man solche Entwicklungsgeschichten wie von sensitiv und sensibel nicht in Wörterbüchern? Die vielen unterschiedlichen lexikografisch-semantischen Dokumentationen und die diversen Antworten der Internetcommunity von Foren und Blogs zeigen das sprachliche Spannungsfeld, in dem sich beide Ausdrücke gerade befinden. Wir sind quasi Zeugen aktueller sprachlicher Veränderungen.
>   (Storjohan)

Comment: Ich denke, _sensibel_ hat einfach noch die weitere Bedeutung _heikel_. Das trifft auf sensible Situationen und auch auf sensible Daten zu.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Auf der neutralen Beobachterebene stimme ich zu, auf der persönlichen Kommentatorebene halte ich die Verwendung beider Wörter für die genannten Fälle für außergewöhnlich ungeschlacht und unbedacht und leider nicht selten dämlich.

Comment: Joa, die Bedeutung von Wörtern wird halt nicht von dir festgelegt, sondern von der Gemeinschaft der Sprecher*innen...

Comment: " 'Sensible Daten' oder 'sensitve Daten' sind natürlich .. ein Ausdruck der allgemeinen Blähsprechverlotterung". Ja, das kann frau so sehen, wenn sie möchte. Bist du auch schon auf die Idee gekommen, dass deine Ausführungen "Blähsprech" sein könnten? Und dass das, was dir persönlich nicht behagt, nicht notwendigerweise "ungeschlacht", "unbedacht " und "dämlich" ist?

Comment: Ja. Kreative Sprachverwendung finde ich gut. Vorgefundene Sprachpraxis finde ich interessant und nehme das meistens wohlwollend zur Kenntnis. Einige sind trotzdem blöd. So hier. Auch wenn es eine Meinung ist, oben stehen die Gründe.

Comment: Hmmm ... die "Blähsprechverlotterung" taucht zum ersten Mal 1998 auf, in der ZEIT, am  10. Juni '98. Zitat: "Auch die On-line-Ausgabe des Berliner Tagesspiegels geht mit sensiblen Daten recht unsensibel um." Ausgerechnet das Zentralorgan der Deutschen Lateinlehrer! :-)) Na so was aber auch!

Comment: @multiplex Wollte ich doch ne Liste mitliefern von all den Gruppen, die ich für soundso halte (not nice!). Aber schau mal aufs Datum: https://www.zeit.de/1983/52/hilfe-aus-karlsruhe Mein wesentlicher Punkt ist mit dem Linguistikartikel konform: Eine solche Wortverwendung ist verwirrend und schlecht dokumentiert/erklärt, wenn nicht gar schlecht erklärbar. Außer: ist halt so. Ferner sage ich gar nicht, das ginge gar nicht ;) Kommaschomalmoche.

Comment: @ LangLangC: Ach, na ja. Wörter verlieren eben manchmal Bedeutungen, Bedeutungen verschieben sich / werden verschoben, es kommen neue hinzu - wer mag das schon in jedem Einzelfall ergründen bzw. könnte es erklären? Und wozu auch? Ansonsten sprechen wir in solchen Fällen wohl von Kontaminationen, die uns ja massenhaft um die Ohren fliegen. Das ganze Jahr hat frau von "warmen Temperaturen" gehört, ständig klagt wer, dass "die Mieten immer teurer werden", neulich sagte einer: "Die Preise (!) werden immer teurer." Man nimmt's zur Kenntnis und macht es selber nicht nach - voilà. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Die [EU-Richtlinie](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations/legal-grounds-processing-data/sensitive-data/what-personal-data-considered-sensitive_de) spricht von *sensiblen Daten*, wobei meiner Meinung nach der Ausdruck nicht besonders glücklich ist, weil nicht die Daten selbst sensibel sind, sondern mit diesen Daten die Persönlichkeitsrechte leicht verletzt werden können.

Selbst wenn man die Anwendung auf Personen beschränkt, gibt es einen Unterschied:

- *Sensitiv* heißt nur, dass man man etwas überhaupt bemerkt, daher auch kommen auch Zusammensetzungen wie *infrarot-sensitiv*, *UV-sensitiv*. *Stilempfinden* ist so eine Kategorie.
- *Sensibel* heißt, dass man auf diesen Unterschied auch noch empfindlich/deutlich reagiert.